# Details on how to write blocking application code in Netty?

Tags: netty

I see the FAQ here http://netty.io/4.0/guide/#faq.4 but I'm looking for more details. (Code from FAQ excerpted below.)
I assume `DefaultEventExecutor` should be `DefaultEventExecutorGroup`, but I'm not finding an overall explanation that leaves me knowing what to put in the `MyHandler` class, or how to handle more complex situations.

- What do you implement in `MyHandler`? `messageReceived`?
- How does information flow from the previous step (`HttpChunkAggregator`) to the `MyHandler`? In other words, what does one handler call to pass a message to the next handler?
- If there were two handlers with blocking code, which could execute in parallel, how would you do that, and then (I guess) combine their results in a 3rd handler that would write the response?

[From [FAQ](http://netty.io/4.0/guide/#faq.4)]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final EventExecutor executor = new DefaultEventExecutor(8);

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(), new NioEventLoopGroup());
    bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(Channel channel) {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());

            // MyHandler contains code that blocks so add it with the
            // EventExecutor to the pipeline.
            pipeline.addLast(executor, "handler", new MyHandler());        
        }
     });

     sb.bind(socketAddress);

     // Other code

  }


   public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
      // Your blocking application code
```

Answer (score 0):

[`BlockingReadHandler`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/queue/BlockingReadHandler.java) might give you an idea although it's for 3.x. It has been removed from 4.0 because it wasn't very useful - most people just want to keep things asynchronous. Please also note that emulating a blocking operation with a reactor-based framework will only degrade performance due to increased context switching.